# How to check if input is valid or not?

Tags: c++, io

In I/O, such as reading data from a file, if the data in the file has a wrong type, how to check it? For example

```
1.2 // in file
```

but read to an integer

```
int i;
in_stream >> i;
```

Comment: Should be `in_stream >> i`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the input is a C++ string, below is the start of a recursive solution to get you going.  I agree with the comments of Joachim and rasen; the approach below follows more along the line suggested by rasen.

The key include here is cctype.  This gives you a boolean check on whether or not a given character is a digit.

As written, the code returns a NULL value if a non-digit is encountered, which shows up as a zero in the returned number; you will need to modify this implementation for your needs.  E.g., note that "23.1" comes back as 2301, where the "." is replaced by a zero.

This is probably not exactly what you want, so think about how you want to implement the logic, maybe return a designated special char, when a non-digit is encountered, or something like that. Then you can search this returned value for the presence of the designated char, providing the basis of a boolean function that will let you know if a given input string can convert to the int data type.

The output of main.cpp (listed below) is:

```
Here is the integer: Invalid character, entry must be a number: 
2301
Here is the integer: 22
Here is the integer: 0
Here is the integer: 1
Here is the integer: 32
```

Code below:

```
//  main.cpp
//  Created by bruce3141 on 7/7/13.

/* Numeric Conversion (string to int)
 * ----------------------
 * Demonstrates a recursive implementation of converting a string into 
 * its representation as an int. Provides feedback to the user on invalid 
 * entries, using isdigit() from the <cctype> import, where a invalid 
 * character (a non-digit) is encountered.
 */

 #include <iostream>
 #include <string>
 #include <cctype>
 using namespace std;


 /* Function prototype */
 int stringToInt(string str);


// Main.cpp tests a few cases below:
int main() {
   int n = 5;
   string strNumbers[5] = {"23.1", "22", "-0", "+1", "32"};
   for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      cout << "Here is the integer: "<< stringToInt(strNumbers[i]) <<endl;
   }
   return 0;
}



/* Convert from string -> int.  The code is longer because of the possibility
* that we might have a '-' or '+' preceding the integer input, and then of
* course multiple digits in combination with the '-' or '+' signs: 
*/
int stringToInt(string str) {

/* Get the number of characters in the string: */
int nS = str.length();

/* Base Case #1: a single positive integer as input: */
if (nS == 1) {
    /* This basic version provides a liitle feedback on
     * invalid entries, using isdigit() from the <cctype>
     import: */
    if (!isdigit(str[0])) {
        cout << "Invalid character, entry must be a number: "<<endl;
        return NULL;
    } else  {
        /* We have to subtract the ASCII code for the character '0' so
         that the string displays as a number in the proper range: */
        return str[0]-'0';
    }

    /* Base Case #2: a single negative integer as input, here
     * we deal with the possibility that a '-' precedes a number: */
} else if (nS == 2 && str.substr(0,1) == "-") {
    /* Below, subtract the ASCII code for the character '0' then
     * multiply by (-1) since the number is negative: */
    return (str[1] - '0')*(-1);

    /* Base Case #3: a single postive integer as input, as indicated
     * by a '+' character: */
} else if (nS == 2 && str.substr(0,1) == "+") {
    /* Below, subtract the ASCII code for the character '0': */
    return (str[1] - '0');

    /* Below is the recursive step for negative numbers with more
     * than one digit: */
} else if (nS >= 2 && str.substr(0,1) == "-") {
    int n1 = stringToInt(str.substr(0,nS-1))*10;
    int n2 = stringToInt(str.substr(nS-1,nS));
    return n1 - n2;

    /* Below is the recursive step for positive numbers with a
     * preceding '+' character and with more than one digit: */
} else if (nS >= 2 && str.substr(0,1) == "+") {
    int n1 = stringToInt(str.substr(0,nS-1))*10;
    int n2 = stringToInt(str.substr(nS-1,nS));
    return n1 + n2;
}

/* Below is the recursive step for positive numbers with more
 * than one digit, but with no preceding '+' character: */
else {
    int n1 = stringToInt(str.substr(0,nS-1))*10;
    int n2 = stringToInt(str.substr(nS-1,nS));
    return n1 + n2;
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

In this case there's not really much you can do. If you try to read a floating-point number into an integer variable, that will not give any error since the stream (with the number in your example) reads the `1` as an integer, which it of course is.

What you *could* do is to [`peek`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/peek) at the next character to see if it is something you expect or not.

Comment: How to check if the next character is expected or not after peeking? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could input your data in string and then analyse whether it is in correct form. If so, then convert it to the type you want.